# How to stop JButton from performing an endless loop

Tags: java, loops, jbutton

Basically what I'm trying to do is continuously append a string of text into a JTextPane when the user clicks a button. The loop will only stop when the user clicks on the button again. This is in my button's actionPerformed method:

```
StyledDocument xpInfo = txtXPInfo.getStyledDocument();
if (btnGo.getText().equals("Go Adventure!")) {
    btnGo.setText("Stop Adventure");

    try {
        do {
            xpInfo.insertString(xpInfo.getLength(), "Some string\n", null);
            txtXPInfo.update(txtXPInfo.getGraphics());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } while (btnGo.getText().equals("Stop Adventure"));
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FrmPlay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

} else if (btnGo.getText().equals("Stop Adventure")) {
    btnGo.setText("Go Adventure!");
}
```

The code I wrote seemed to be an endless loop. I thought it might be because I did all those in the button's actionPerformed method, but I have no idea how else to make it. I'm sorry if this is such a stupid question. I give my thanks in advance to anyone who's willing to answer this question!

Comment: While I don't do Swing, Sleeping, or looping like this on the event thread is a bad idea. [You should probably look into timers.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: @WalterM I looked into it and I'll probably change it into a timer. I didn't know how else to delay other than using Thread.sleep() so that was what I used. And I know the looping is a bad idea, I just have no idea how else to make it work. Thanks anyway for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ScheduledExecutorService` as its main purpose is executing tasks on separate thread with some specified time interval. But you need to keep in mind that *all UI-related operations must be done from EDT*, so you should wrap `txtXPInfo` updating operations with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService xpInfoScheduledExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
private ScheduledFuture<?> xpInfoUpdatingFuture;

public void actionPerformed() {
    StyledDocument xpInfo = txtXPInfo.getStyledDocument();
    if (btnGo.getText().equals("Go Adventure!")) {
        btnGo.setText("Stop Adventure");
        xpInfoUpdatingFuture = xpInfoScheduledExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                new XpInfoUpdater(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } else if (btnGo.getText().equals("Stop Adventure")) {
        xpInfoUpdatingFuture.cancel(true);
        btnGo.setText("Go Adventure!");
    }
}

private class XpInfoUpdater implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                xpInfo.insertString(xpInfo.getLength(), "Some string\n", null);
                txtXPInfo.update(txtXPInfo.getGraphics());
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you're blocking the `Event Thread`. In Swing, there's only a single thread that the OS uses to dispatch UI events (like a button press).

In your case, It *appears* that you're looping infinitely on that thread. If you are, then the other button presses will never register, because that thread is busy with your `do/while` loop.

What you really want to do is start a different thread (there are lots of examples of this) that do the append loop, and leave the `Event Thread` for dispatching UI events.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand Event Thread. Do you have a recommendation of where I should read about it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried reading it but there are just too many things I don't understand. I'll probably try to read about it again later. Thanks anyway for the recommendation, it is good to learn about new stuffs!